# How to clean similar code

Tags: java, coding-style

I want to do a deep copy of data in system. I have this kind of class:

```
Class User{
    User mother;
    User father;
    User spouse;
}
```

After I create individual records, I want to rebuild their references like this:

```
Map<User, User> motherMap = new HashMap<User, User>();
Map<User, User> fatherMap = ...;
Map<User, User> spouseMap = ...;

//Now I want to populate User reference like this:
for(User user : motherMap.keySet) {
    //some other similar code;
    user.setMother(motherMap.get(user));
} 
for(User user : fatherMap.keySet) {
    //some other similar code;
    user.setFather(fatherMap.get(user));
}
for(User user : motherMap.keySet) {
    //some other similar code;
    user.setSpouse(spouseMap.get(user));
}
```

Any idea how I can clean up this kind of similar code? I want to make my code nicer because in real code there are more than 10 reference between Users. Intellij warns this method is too complex to analyze, and I feel I only do copy paste...

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Some description would be nice

Comment: Which is the "master" set of data?  Are the instances of User in control, and the three Maps are derived from them, or are the Maps in control, and the User instances are derived from the maps?  In your example code you seem to be doing the later but more explanation is needed.  BTW, I think having the Maps "in control" is a dubious idea.

Comment: I agree that it's unclear based on the example code.  The fact that the _pseudo code_ seems to create **new** maps is confusing.  This kinda suggests that the code should populate the maps, but common sense suggests that we're trying to populate _User_ objects.

Comment: I want to do a deep copy of users from other system. First of all, I created users with no reference to others and store their relations in maps. Then after I persist them, I want to rebuild their relations from those maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to create a set of all the keys from all your maps:

```
Set<User> allUsers = new HashSet<User>();

allUsers.addAll(motherMap.keySet());
allUsers.addAll(fatherMap.keySet());
allUsers.addAll(spouseMap.keySet());

for (User u : allUsers) {
    u.setMother(motherMap.get(u));
    u.setFather(fatherMap.get(u));
    u.setSpouse(spouseMap.get(u));
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. I finally decide to use reflection to update those fields.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to filter the class by using

```
instance of
```

Comment: Huh?  What are you talking about?

Comment: A couple of days ago I had a similar issue. There were a couple of sub-classes and needed to know which one was used to use the right command. 
By time I found out the instance of operator is mostly forgotten if you're dealing with subclasses

Comment: This question has nothing to do with _instanceof_.  What classes and/or sub-classes would it be used to distinguish between?

Comment: They are all User objects.

Comment: Also, `instanceof` is one word...